# How can I add a sorter to the admin change list in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

In my application i have to add a a link that sort the admin list page. Sorting has to be done based on a field which is not in the list_display.

My model is

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    published_on = models.DateTimeField('Date Published')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('Date Created')
```

and my admin file is

```
class PageAdmin(PageModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'published_on')
core.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

I just need to add a link "Recently added" in admin list page to sort the list based on created_on which is not added to list_display. Any suggestions please

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, are you asking how to sort by `created_on` without adding it to the `list_display`?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess at what you mean;

If what you wanted was to add a filter for `created_on` without adding it to your `list_display`, you simply add it as a `list_filter`

```
class PageAdmin(PageModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'published_on')
    list_filter = ('created_on',) # The comma is important here
admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

Comment: yes I want to sort by created_on without adding it to the list_display. I have tried to add it as a filter how can i make it sort? My requirement is I have a link in the admin list page. On clicking the link the list should be sorted in the descending order and display the recently added ones.

Comment: Do you mind posting the code or posting any errors? I tried this and the items on the admin page are sorted fine, without the column being present

Answer (score 0):

there are a few options. if you always want your pages sorted, you can add `ordering` to your model, which will order them for all queries

```
class Page(...):
    field = ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['published_on']
```

for more on this, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering)

You could also override the queryset for your particular modelAdmin:

```
class PageAdmin(...):
    list_display = ...

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PageAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.order_by('published_on')
```

have a feeling this only works if ordering isn't set, but can't remember now. Info on this is also in [the docs,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods) (sorry, no direct link to method)